# Are hotspots sold inside phones?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, carriers

My idea is this: It would be really convenient if i could buy a smartphone with an integrated mobile hotspot so i dont have to carry around a separate device. So is this sold? if so, by whom and approximately how expensive can this get? (assume carrier is irrelevant, i can easily switch to another if Verizon doesn't work)

Comment: I'd say most of the Android phone support this out of the box. You can also buy MiFi device if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Some SmartPhones like the Samsung Galaxy S2 lets you create a Wi-Fi hotspot. Unfortunately, this would decrease the phone's battery life, which is why having a separate device would be better option.

Comment: The Motorolo Droid Bionic also supports a hotspot mode.   Don't even think about it if the phone isn't on the charger...

Answer (score 2):

This feature is called **WiFI Tethering**, it comes with most modern Android devices. You can read more about it on our [wifi-tether tag.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi-tethering?sort=votes&pagesize=50)